# Building Docker Images over remote repositories Artifactory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, artifactory, remote-repository

I use Artifactory as remote repository to build my docker image. Now befor I execute the command `$ docker build` I have to change the docker file so that each line should be changed.

```
FROM rocker/shiny
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
.
.
.
```

There are roughly 100 lines in the docker file.
In order to say that `docker build` should run over `Artifactory` I have to change every line like as follows:

```
FROM docker-remote-docker-io.artifacts/rocker/shiny
```

Is there any possibility to set `docker` or change `. ~/.profile` to avoid the changeing every line in the docher file?

The option `URL` in `docker build` is not what I need! ;)

Comment: Why would you need to change every line? Juste changing the `FROM` instruction should be sufficient, no?

Comment: Unfortunatly, it is not enough I get the error messages like:
Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'

Comment: this one looks like more a network issue when building rather than a `FROM` instruction issue. I suppose the command `apt-get update` fails and gives this error? Can you access `deb.debian.org` from the machine running the build? (or the machine on which Docker Daemon running the build is installed?)

Comment: If you're on a corporate network and docker hub is blocked then Debian may well be blocked too. You'll have to mirror the apt-get repo too

Comment: @PierreB.: the problem is as 'KeepCalmAndCarryO' described, that my machine is on a corporate network.  It means, the docker file cannot call debian files via Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you are building but you can setup a [proxy to dockerhub](https://medium.com/@andrenit/docker-and-artifactory-as-a-registry-mirror-1365891b39c5)

> Luckly there is a feature on Docker Engine that goes mostly unnoticed:
>   the “--registry-mirror” daemon option. Engine options are configured
>   somewhat differently on each Linux distro, but in CentOS/RHEL you can
>   do it editing the “/etc/sysconfig/docker” file and restarting Docker:

This way you don't have to change your `FROM` lines

Comment: Thanks for your responce. If I set the mirror, would it solve the problem with debian distribution?

Comment: You'll probably need a Debian mirror too, I would guess. Alternatively you can build a base image with all the Debian packages you want in docker hub then use that as your base image via the docker hub proxy